# Pas vs. Non quelle est la différence?

Tags: négation

Quel est la différence entre 'pas seulement' et 'non seulement'!?

Answer (score 3):

« Pas seulement » est le plus souvent la deuxième partie d'une négation (ne + verbe + pas seulement) mais il peut aussi être utilisé seul.

« Non seulement » introduit obligatoirement une suite avec deux termes.

> — Cette règle s'applique-t-elle aux élèves ?
>
> — Pas seulement ! = Cette règle ne s'applique pas seulement au élèves.
>
> Non seulement cette règle s'applique au élèves, mais elle s'applique aussi...